# Problema con run build en tailwind

Tags: laravel, tailwind

Instalé Taildwind CSS en laravel 10, pero cuando quiero hacer un cambio siempre tengo que ejecutar php run build. Hay alguna manera para no hacer esto en cada cambio?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: `php run build` no será `npm run build` ?

Comment: Sí, está explicado en la documentación [Running Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#running-vite)

Answer (score 0):

corre en la terminal `npm run dev` , esto hará que cada cambio sea "escuchado" y no tengas que ejecutar siempre `npm run build`.

Comment: Build no es para probar la aplicación.

Comment: Saludos Rodrigo, nadie ha dicho lo contrario. Entiendo que él se refiere a cuando esta trabajando en la aplicación para poder ver los css de tailwind sin tener la necesidad de compilarlos mediante el npm run build, es por esto que utilizando npm run dev puedes ver reflejado todos los cambios que vayas haciendo.

Comment: El build ya se utiliza ya cuando quieres hacer un compilado de todo los assets de la aplicación y subirlo al servidor, por ejemplo.

Comment: Como se dice en uno de los comentarios arriba, en la documentación se explica.